# Why doesn't the CSS kick in for max-device-width: 480px?

Tags: iphone, css, media-queries

```
media="(max-device-width: 480px), only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), all and (max-width: 480px)"
```

Hi all,

The CSS is working fine on a desktop with a viewport of 480px or less as intended but it doesn't kick in on iPhone. Any idea what could be wrong with the media query code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the viewport meta tag in place?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```